# Browserify / Electron / AngularJS Error: fs.existsSync is not a function

Tags: node.js, angularjs, electron, browserify

I'm getting a **Error: fs.existsSync is not a function** code after I bundle my code using Browserify.

Before I've tried to use require() but I kept getting **Error: require is not defined** due to require function not supported on client side. Browserify seems a solution to use. I've managed to solve require error with browserify but another one came up - fs.existsSync is not a function.

Here is the error code as shown on my console:

```
Error: fs.existsSync is not a function
[159]</</sqlite.prototype.connect@http://127.0.0.1:8080/services/bundle.js:169566:35
[160]</<@http://127.0.0.1:8080/services/bundle.js:169992:29
invoke@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:4718:19
enforcedReturnValue@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:4557:37
invoke@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:4718:19
createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:4517:37
getService@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:4664:39
injectionArgs@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:4688:58
instantiate@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:4730:18
$controller@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:10369:28
compile/<@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular-ui-router.js:4081:28
bind/<@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:1247:18
invokeLinkFn@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:9934:9
nodeLinkFn@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:9335:11
compositeLinkFn@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:8620:13
publicLinkFn@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:8500:30
lazyCompilation@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:8844:25
updateView@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular-ui-router.js:4021:23
compile/</<@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular-ui-router.js:3959:11
$broadcast@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:18005:28
transitionTo/$state.transition<@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular-ui-router.js:3352:22
processQueue@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:16383:28
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:16399:27
$eval@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:17682:28
$digest@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:17495:31
$apply@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:17790:24
done@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:11831:47
completeRequest@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:12033:7
requestLoaded@http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/assets/js/vendors/angular.js:11966:9
 <div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

I'm using electron, angularjs and sqlite to build my app but I'm stuck on this error, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve my error without browserify by enabling `nodeIntegration: true` in main.js file (electron entry file). Then I was able to load my script (coolscript.js) which has require function inside of it to my html without problems -

```
<script>
   require('coolscript.js')
</script>
```